# What is the most easy way to port my CefSharp based parsers (.net framework 4.7.2) on Linux?

Tags: c#, .net, linux, cefsharp, chromium-embedded

For whole my life I didn't coded even "Hello world!" program for Linux. I have a lot of parsers. They all based on CefSharp. Now I need to port them on Linux. That hurts.

I tried to run them under Wine, but it crash at startup.

Then I found CefGlue, compiled it's WPF demo for Windows and tried to run it under Wine, well, it does not crash now, instead I see purple background window that display nothing and nothing works.

What else I can do to solve my problems? Maybe there are some other Cef based libs that will work on Linux?

I use Cef browser, because it is easy to open needed URL and execute JS scripts to get needed data.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know CefSharp but from what I can see in the Quick Start, there is a [.NET Core](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/Quick-Start#installation-ms-net-core-31net-50net-60) version. So what you need to do is to migrate your application to a .Net Core version (6.0 if possible since it's currently the latest).

You can find [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/porting/) on how to do that. There are some tools to assist you.

Make sure that all your other package dependencies are also migrated to .NET Core or are compatible.

Then you should be able to build your application to run in a Linux environment.

Comment: Thank you. So I compile it as usual for Windows and then run under Wine?

Comment: When using .Net Core application, your application will be built into a DLL file. Then with the dotnet runtime you can run it on Windows or Linux without any third party tool like Wine.

Comment: CefSharp is built with Visual C++ which only runs on Windows. Microsoft have said they won't port Visual C++ to Linux so there's no official way to run a CefSharp app on Linux.